# How can I export the cards from the Trello stack as a list?

Tags: export, trello-cards, trello-lists

How can I export the cards from the Trello stack as a list?

Is it possible to export a simple list of just the cards, sorted by which column they are in and in the order they appear.

So

Backlog

```
Date modified   Card text

Date modified   Card text

Date modified   Card text
```

To Do

```
Date modified   Card text

Date modified   Card text
```

Etc.

Is there a way that will just show me what cards have moved since a specific date?

Answer (score 4):

This is now available as a paid "business-class" [feature](https://trello.com/card/bulk-data-export-for-organizations/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1289).

There is also a free [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trelloexport/nhdelomnagopgaealggpgojkhcafhnin?hl=en) that downloads the current board as an excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

The free version of trello allows you to export your data to JSON.

Just upload the JSON file to [json-csv.com](https://json-csv.com) and you will be able to open the data up in a spreadsheet.

Then you can sort the data whichever way you like.

Comment: More info here: http://help.trello.com/article/924-making-sense-of-trellos-json-export

Answer (score 3):

If you are comfortable with using the browser console, the following JavaScript snippet from [this blog post](http://www.secretgeek.net/trello_ws) will copy the the board, list and card titles sorted as requested to the clipboard in Markdown format. However, you will not be able to access the date modified this way.

```
var s = [];
s.push("# " + jQuery(".board-header").children()[0].innerText);
jQuery(".list:has(.list-header-name)").each(function() {
    s.push("\n## " + jQuery(this).find(".list-header-name")[0].value + "\n");
    jQuery(this).find(".list-card-title").each(function() {
        s.push("* " + this.innerText);
    });
});
copy(s.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a new script, on the basis of @mrts answer, but which allows to only export one list with a specific Title.
For convenience, it also exports card labels.
Found it useful to export resolved issues after update :

```
//to edit
const board_name = "Client update - 1.0.0"
var s = [];
jQuery(".list:has(.list-header-name)").each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).find(".list-header-name-assist")[0].innerText !== board_name) { return}
    jQuery(this).find("a.list-card").each(function() {
        let title = jQuery(this).find(".list-card-title")[0].innerText;
        let labels = [];
         jQuery(this).find(".card-label").each(function() {
            let labelText = jQuery(this).find(".label-text")[0].innerText;
            labels.push(labelText)
         })
        s.push("* " + "**"+labels.join(',') + '** - ' + title);
    });
});
copy(s.join("\n"));
console.log(s.length + ' cards of '+board_name+' copied')
```